# How to identify Azure Service Bus queue is empty

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm working on an application which processes messages from multiple Azure Service Bus queues. In order to optimize resources, I need to prioritize one queue and process its messages first. Once it's empty, process the next queue. In order to do that, I'm searching for a method to find if particular queue is empty. It would be really good if there's any way to set an empty-queue-listener.

Currently I have implemented my code to process just one queue with ServiceBusProcessorClient.

```java
this.processor = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
          .connectionString(connectionString)
          .processor()
          .queueName(queueName)
          .processMessage(onMessage)
          .processError(onError)
          .disableAutoComplete()
          .prefetchCount(1) 
          .maxConcurrentCalls(1)
          .receiveMode(ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK)
          .buildProcessorClient();
```

Comment: Please see [QueueRuntimeProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.queueruntimeproperties?view=azure-java-stable). Using this, you can get the number of messages in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav Mantri mentioned in the comment, you can use [getTotalMessageCount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.models.queueruntimeproperties.gettotalmessagecount?view=azure-java-stable) to get the number of messages in the queue.